# GTK+ GTkStatusIcon not working in Win32

Tags: c, winapi, gtk

I cannot get GTkStatusIcon working in Windows and I get no errors. And I make a call to both gtk_status_icon_set_from_file and gtk_status_icon_new_from_file. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I tried with .ico files and .png and still nothing...

Comment: what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Do you declare the GtkStatusIcon to be `static` like this:
`static GtkStatusIcon *status_icon = NULL;`?
Follow [this](http://live.gnome.org/GtkStatusIconTutorial) tutorial and see if it works then.